# Invalid Log Path

Tags: android-studio

Log path '/home/oscar/.AndroidStudio1.5/system/log' is inaccessible.
If you have modified the 'idea.log.path' property please make sure it is correct,
otherwise please re-install the IDE.

Some help please¡¡¡

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the problem for me was that the drive for which Android Studios launched from was full. Full to the very brim, no memory left at all. So I just removed a "heavy" folder (and obviously a non-mandatory folder, it was some IDE installed package which I wasn't using), thus clearing out some space. Voila! Android Studios was able to boot properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. After deleting the temp file my problem was solved. For Windows just Go to Run-> type "%temp%" hit the enter button-> delete all the file under Temp directory. Thank you...